# Resharper - Property not documented

Tags: c#, resharper

I wanted to know if anyone has worked out how to disable the "Public property 'Foo' is not documented" code inspection in Resharper 4.5

I find this really annoying and would really like to disable it on the R# level

Thanks
Amar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a ReSharper warning - it's a Visual Studio one. In the project properties, on the Build tab there is a box named "Suppress warnings" - add 1591 to that box.

Comment: Brilliant! Works like a charm :)

A quick question, is there anyway to turn this off at the IDE level, or do I have to change all of my projects individually (accross all the solutions I work on, there are a LOT)?

Comment: You can put it in the template .csproj (or .vbproj if that's your poison) files I would imagine.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the red bulb, and select "Inspection options for ...". You can then tell Resharper how (and if) to alert you.

Comment: I couldnt see that option. It appears it was VS, and I need to suppress this particular warning on the project level